# Trap signal and cleanup in while loop

Tags: bash

I have this script:

```
FINISH=0;
trap 'FINISH=1' SIGINT

INTERVAL=100;

while true
do
    START=`date +%s`;
    php-cgi -f process.php;
    STOP=`date +%s`;
    ELAPSED=$(($STOP-$START));
    SLEEP=$(($INTERVAL-$ELAPSED));
    if [ $SLEEP -gt 0 ]
    then
        echo "sleeping for $SLEEP seconds";
        sleep $SLEEP;
    fi
    if [ $FINISH -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo "exit";
        break;
    fi
done
```

But it doesnt work as I would like - I want it to just set FINISH=1 but it kills currently executed command (php-cgi or sleep) - how to avoid this? Actually I don't want it to kill php-cgi...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'exit' SIGINT

interval=100;

while true
do
    start=$(date +%s)
    nohup php-cgi -f process.php
    stop=$(date +%s)
    ((elapsed = stop - start))
    ((sleep = interval - elapsed))
    if (( sleep > 0 ))
    then
        echo "sleeping for $sleep seconds"
        sleep "$sleep"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Hmm, so this means that when SIGINT will be 'cought' then the script will exit but php-cgi will continue till it finishes yes?

Comment: @user606521: That's the idea.